# Do I need to create an EC2 instance to remotely access my Amazon RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Do I need to create an EC2 instance in order to remotely connect to my Amazon RDS instance?

I understand that setting up an Amazon RDS instance automagically creates an EC2 instance 'in the background'. But when looking into my EC2 console I don't see that hidden instance so I can't find the details for the public DNS or Elastic IP, neither the EC2 instance key that I need to connect through SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an RDS instance creates an EC2 instance to run the database but you don't have direct access to it via ssh, which is kind of the point.

RDS is a service that is managed for you and the idea is to hide the implementation details and simply provide an endpoint to connect to from another EC2 instance. You can find the endpoint name in the EC2 console - just use this as the hostname to connect to from your application and you can treat RDS just like any other database.

Amazon need to maintain a level of control over the server in order to provide it as a service and ssh access would interfere with that. There are a few things you miss out on because of this (e.g. direct access to DB files) but these are far outweighed by having Amazon manage upgrades, backups and replication for you.